# How to create a zombie process that cannot be reaped for a few minutes

Tags: c++, c, linux, zombie-process

Could someone suggest me an easy way to create a zombie process that cannot be reaped for a few minutes.
The purpose of this is to test parent process for being able to reap zombies processes after they become reapable again.

One case for non-reapable zombies can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19059615/process-stuck-in-exit-shows-as-zombie-but-cannot-be-reaped). I guess there might be easier ways to do so.

OS: Linux

Preferable languages: C/C++

Comment: Define zombie process? else you might as well make a process that do `sleep(ETERNAL);`

Comment: @Surt I think [tag:zombie-process] tag perfectly defines these beasts :)

Comment: Before overengineering here, can't you just start a thread and then no join it? or doesn't that count?

Comment: @Surt Well, I want to test parent process without changing its code. And it does wait for children.

Comment: Would the downvoter comment its vote? As I do not see any wrong with the question

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little program that will cause a zombie to show up in your "ps aux" output for a few minutes.  Note the commented-out waitpid() call; if you un-comment that call, the zombie will not show up, as the waitpid() call causes the parent process to claim its dead child.

(Disclaimer:  I only tested this under MacOS/X since that's the computer I'm at, but it should work the same under Linux)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main()
{
   printf("Starting Program!\n");

   int pid = fork();
   if (pid == 0)
   {
      printf("Child process %i is running!\n", getpid());
      sleep(300);  // wait 5 minutes
      printf("Child process %i is exiting!\n", getpid());
      return 0;
   }
   else if (pid > 0)
   {
      printf("Parent process is continuing child's pid is %i...\n", pid);
      sleep(5);  // just for clarity
      printf("Parent process is sending SIGKILL to child process...\n");
      if (kill(pid, SIGKILL) != 0) perror("kill");
      // waitpid(pid, NULL, 0);  // uncomment this to avoid zombie child process

      printf("Parent process is sleeping... ps aux should show process #%i is a zombie now\n", pid);
      sleep(500);  // just for clarity
      printf("Parent process is exiting!\n");
   }
   else perror("fork()");
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Though as I mentioned I need a zombie that cannot be reaped for some period of time. You get zombie because you do not reap it - It's a different case

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the obvious - living processes can't be reaped. Keep the process alive and that's that.

Similarly, you can nest the process within a container process that refuses to die and since that container process is the new parent and it isn't doing any reaping nor relinquishing its control over its child, no one can reap the child (well... "grandchild" anyway).

If you want the OS to avoid reaping your process, than you might be in luck on macOS (tested on Big Sur). MacOS will forget to reap a child process if it is forcibly terminated and its parent is also forcibly terminated without ever reaping the child.

The process will show up with `ps aux`, however the system never seems to reap the crashed child and resources appear to remain in use (used files, open sockets, memory, etc').

So essentially you can take the answer @jeremy-friesner offered and nest it within a process and you're done.

If these weren't any of the desired effects, than I may have misunderstood the question.

Comment: The MacOS behavior seems like a severe bug, or else something is wrong with your tests.  Reaping of orphan zombies is a really basic function of Unix-like systems.  And in any case, a process's memory, files, etc, should get freed as soon as it exits, before it ever enters the zombie state.

Comment: @NateEldredge - I agree, but so far the only cure is to restart. The old parent receives the `SIGCHLD` but never reaped and when it dies the process ownership passes to PID 1 (root), but for some reason it isn't properly reaped (no repeated signal, I guess). Then again, I tried only while running code from terminal (which meant there were a few more parents in the chain) and then quoting the terminal, so the issue might be hiding somewhere else. And when I crashed my processes... I did it well and good :)

Comment: So `ps aux` shows the child running, having PPID = 1, *and* in zombie state?

Comment: @NateEldredge , `ps aux` places the child in parenthesis (which I think means it is no longer running), with  PPID = 1, but it never gets reaped (I assume this is because the signal for the child is never raised and the signal processed for the father doesn't reap the child). I cannot test the kernel, but I can break it (which isn't a lot of fun, since it requires me to restart).

Comment: I don't know offhand how MacOS ps formats its output, but on the Unix systems I know, a zombie process doesn't have its command name printed at all (you get something like `<defunct>` instead).  Parentheses are more likely to mean something like "process is alive but swapped out". I would look at the STAT column instead, which would be Z for a zombie.

Comment: @NateEldredge - thanks, didn't look at that... it says `?E`... which means ... ‍♂️

Comment: If it's like [FreeBSD's ps](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?ps(1)), the `E` means "trying to exit".  I'd guess it might be taking a long time to write out output, or delete unreferenced files that are being closed, or write a core dump, or something like that; something like high system load or hardware problems could contribute to this. But it couldn't become a zombie until those things have finished.  And when they are, I suspect it'll be immediately reaped by `init` instead of becoming a zombie.